# replace values by NAN

Tags: python, dataframe, nan

I've got a dataframe that looks like this;

```
[index, Data]
[1, [5,3,6,8,4,5,7etc]]
```

The data in my "data"column stays in an array. I need to have at least 75 values in each array. The dataframe is 438 rows long.
I need to make a filter where all the arrays that contains less than 75 values, will be replaced by NaN.

I thought of something like this:

```
for i in range(len(df_window)):
if len(df_window['Data'][i][0])<75:
```

I don't know if this is right and how to continue. The dataframe called df_window

can someone help me quick please?

Comment: Why do you want NaN? Are you sure None wouldn't be better? Or maybe removing those rows from the data entirely?

Comment: The reason i want to get NaN's is because i want to delete these rows afterwards. But I have two different dataframes where these NaN's row should be deleted if you understand what i mean. Because after al this filtering i want to compare those two dataframes to eachother so the layout of the two have to be the same

Comment: If I understand you, you have 2 dataframes, each with 438 rows, and you want to do some row by row comparison. In that case, it may make sense to have the check for length>75 as part of whatever the comparison function is, since you're going to need to check for NaNs in the comparison function anyway.

Comment: yess indeed. So at the end of the script i want to devide those two dataframes by eachother. But to do that, i have to make the dataframes exactly the same. arrays with less than 75 values could be seen as 'manipulated' and have to be removed. So that row has to be removed at both frames. Atfer this i need to make the length of each row the same for both frames by looking which of the two have less values and make the other the same amount of values. Can you help?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `lengths = df_window['Data'].apply(len)` to get the serie of array lengths. Then by using `df_window.loc[(lengths < 75), 'Data'] = np.nan` you should get what you want.

EDIT: Corrected first line.

Comment: Because it is a list in a single cell the output of the .apply(len) is 1 for each row, so that is not working. So i have to find another solution for this. The thing i did above in the for loop gives me the lengths of the arrays. The only thing is that i dont know how to replace it by nan afterward

Comment: Oh yes indeed, then use lengths = df_window['Data'].apply(len).

Comment: that worked, thanks! Do you also know how i have to do the following thing: I need to look if there is a difference between both arrays. so for example in df1 the array in row 1 has 80 values and in df2 the same row has 78 values. Therefore i need to search for each row which df array has the least values and i need to make them both the same. So i think (if i have 78 and 80) i need to make the one with 80 also 78 by picking in this case the last 78 values. I have to do that for each row

Comment: Hey! Well yes you can do like this https://jovian.ai/dev-perrier-remi/so-replace-by-nan I made a notenook it was easier. Replace 0 by your column name and everything is good. However it's a bit slow, you want to avoid for loop on dataframe but it should be ok.